# jQuery: Is there a way to animate a div's width without any text movement?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm using jQuery to shrink a `div`'s width, like this:

```
$('div#foo').animate({width: 0},someSpeed);
```

While it's shrinking, the text reflows to fit the ever-thinner `div`. I don't want this to happen - I want the text to stay as it is, just disappearing from view as the width decreases, as happens if you do `$('div#foo').slideUp()`.

Is there a CSS trick or some other way to make this work?

Comment: OT: How do you cope with the text contents being re-displayed after the width reaches 0? I have to use append `.hide(0)` to keep the text hidden - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/AvYyT/

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I actually did this originally, but I simplified it for my question: `$(this).animate({width: 0, opacity: 0},speed,function(){$(this).css('display','none');});`. So when it's done with the animate, it sets display to none.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/AvYyT/1/

The trick is to use an inner container and set its with to the width of the outer container.

Comment: Yup, that seems to be what he's looking for. Noted.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `white-space: nowrap;` on the `div`. The only problem there is that you will have to manually add line breaks if you have a long body of text.

Comment: This works with max-width, in which case you might want to also use `overflow: auto`, and requires no extra elements.

Comment: how can we do this when we have long text and text is dyanmic

Comment: @jitendravarshney If you have a different question, then it's best to ask a new question

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to set the width of the content to the with of the `div`, add `overflow:hidden` to the `div` and only then reduce the width.

Something like (untested, could have typos, but you get the idea...):

```
var el = $('div#foo');
el.children().each(function() {
  $(this).width(el.width());
});
el.css('overflow', 'hidden').animate({width: 0}, someSpeed);
```

But it depends on the contents of the `div`, this would not work if there are images inside it.

Comment: Setting the child width to the exact value of the parent width is not safe. If the child has padding, margins and/or borders, the child will become to wide, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/AvYyT/3/. In order to deal with this, you have to subtract the difference `$(this).outerWidth(true) - $(this).width()`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/AvYyT/4/

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Like I said, it depends on the contents of the `div`, I am merely illustrating the idea with a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

In your div CSS, use: `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: @David If you're guessing, guess in a comment. Post an answer only if you're somewhat certain that it works.

Comment: @Šime, how do you know  he was not 'fairly certain' it work, whatever that means? You know you're sort of a StackOverflow bully, right?

Comment: overflow:hidden only hides content when reflow cannot adjust it to the new space.

Comment: @Dutchie I've requested moderator attention. I don't think that I went overboard, but we'll see...

Comment: My apologies. I was wrong. I'll take your advise into consideration, thanks for being diplomatic.

Comment: @Šime I personally don't think moderator attention is required, or I would have requested it myself. I just thought you should know there is a polite way of stating things. From your rep and your answers, I can see you know what you're talking about - I would just encourage you to try giving polite critique, rather than simply criticizing every little thing.

Comment: @Šime Thanks for understanding. Hopefully between today and yesterday we can shake hands and move on.

Comment: Things seem pretty civil here, thanks for working out the differences fellas.

Answer (score -2):

try giving it `vertical-align:top`

Comment: If you're guessing, guess in a comment. Post an answer only if you're somewhat certain that it works.